# Erro ao desserializar Json .NET CORE 5 - JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected

Tags: json, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, github

Basicamente criei um project API no .NET 5. Minha ideia é consumir a API deles (Pegar informações de repositórios), e então disponibilizar algumas informações na minha API. A requisição é bem sucedida porém sempre ocorre o mesmo erro na parte de converter um JSON para um objeto.

RepositoriesController:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class RepositoriesController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    private readonly ILogger<RepositoriesController> _logger;

    public RepositoriesController(ILogger<RepositoriesController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(string number)
    {
        return Ok(ProcessRepositories());
    }

    private static async Task ProcessRepositories()
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.github.v3+json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", ".NET Foundation Repository Reporter");

        var streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync("https://api.github.com/orgs/dotnet/repos?sort=created&per_page=5&direction=desc");
        var repositories = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Repository>>(await streamTask);
    }
}
```

Classe repository:

```
 public class Repository
{
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string node_id { get; set; }
    //public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Porém sempre no trecho:

```
        var repositories = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Repository>>(await streamTask);
```

O navegador me retorna o erro:

> JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either
> be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum
> allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on
> JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.

Queria entender porque só com duas propriedades ou até mesmo uma acaba dando esse erro.

Documentação da api do github:

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos

Como base para entender o funcionamento da requisição API usei a documentação oficial da microsoft:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient#deserialize-the-json-result

Answer (score -1):

Eu não entendi bem porém era algo relacionado ao corpo da response.

Basicamente:

```
 var streamTask = client
                   .GetStreamAsync("https://api.github.com/orgs/dotnet/repos?sort=created&per_page=5&direction=desc");
        var repositories = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Repository>>(await streamTask);
```

Foi para

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var response = client
                .GetAsync("https://api.github.com/orgs/dotnet/repos?sort=created&per_page=5&direction=desc").Result;
            string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var repositories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Repo>>(responseBody);
```